# Do all materials get warmed by the sun, or do there exist materials which reflect the major part of the IR radiation?

Tags: thermodynamics, sun, infrared-radiation

Once upon a time, on a hot day, (in a country far, far away, where the internet doesn't exist) I was wondering when I felt that all things around me on which the sun shined were feeling warm:

Do all things around me get warmed by the sun? Or do there exist materials which reflect the major part of the infrared radiation coming from that beautiful sun, so these materials don't warm up in her? Or maybe there are certain circumstances which cause some materials to reflect the major part of that soothing radiation?

I had no means to do research (i.e. I'm just too lazy on this sunny morning in Holland, where I can see the still wet trees in the garden dumping in the sun,  to do some research), and that's why I'm asking the question to people who aren't as lazy as I am this morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radiation is either reflected or absorbed.

It is not infrared that is absorbed only, but the whole [sun spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight)

[image]

can be absorbed and degrade down to infrared black body radiation  according to the final temperature.  The colors play a role on how much of the visible radiation is absorbed, mirrors reflect most, black absorbs most and turns it into heat .

In general objects exposed to the sun reach a black body equilibrium temperature at which they reradiate and it is felt as heat. [This table](http://www.solarmirror.com/fom/fom-serve/cache/43.html) shows the coefficients for emissivity and absorbptivity  , and one can see that there are coatings with different coefficients to the black body radiation. How hot an object gets in the sun is a matter of balance, the third collumn in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Metals have high reflectivity all over the visible and IR parts of the spectrum, and aluminum would be best.

But a sheet of aluminum in the sun would not have a temperature lower than the surrounding air. And of coarse metals are good conductors of heat, so it would feel warm or hot to the touch.